# Change background color of selectInput in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

My example code:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  selectInput("select1", "Choose: ", c("Alt1.1", "Alt1.2"), selected = c("Alt1.1"), selectize = FALSE, multiple = TRUE),
  br(),
  selectInput("select2", "Choose: ", c("Alt2.1", "Alt2.2"), selected = c("Alt2.1"), selectize = FALSE, multiple = TRUE)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How do I have to change the code so that the background color of the widgets is red for `select1` and blue for `select2`?

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```
div(selectInput("select1", "Choose: ", c("Alt1.1", "Alt1.2"), selected = c("Alt1.1"), selectize = FALSE, multiple = TRUE), style = "background-color: red")
```

[image]

But this is not what I am looking for! Instead I want the background of the options to be red!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Edited as requested in the comments below

You can add CSS through style tags as follows:

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  tags$style("#select1 {border: 2px solid #dd4b39;}"),
  selectInput("select1", "Choose: ", c("Alt1.1", "Alt1.2"), selected = c("Alt1.1"), selectize = FALSE, multiple = TRUE),
  br(),
  tags$style("#select2 {background-color:blue;}"),
  selectInput("select2", "Choose: ", c("Alt2.1", "Alt2.2"), selected = c("Alt2.1"), selectize = FALSE, multiple = TRUE)
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Florian, thanks for your fast and helpful response. The thing I requested first is way too much. Can you tell me if there is an attribute to color the borders of the alternative box? If I use `div(selectInput(...), style = "border: 2px solid #dd4b39;")` it creates a border that also includes the label "Choose:". Thanks for your time!

Comment: That is because you apply the style to the entire div surrounding the selectinput. I updated my answer to show how you could achieve what you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nice option with CSS

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following as a last argument to your `fluidPage`:

```
    tags$style(
        HTML('
                          #select1{
                          background-color: #ff0000;
                          }
                          #select2{
                          background-color: #0000ff;
                          }
                          '
        )
    )
```

That way you are adding custom CSS to your app. Passing this to `fluidPage` should do the job for small changes but if you adjust a lot of elements with CSS you might find it easier to save a `.css` file in the `www` directory of your app.

Comment: I need help with the selectInput in R shiny, kindly help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501999/highlighting-the-initial-element-of-a-specific-selectinput-in-r-shiny